# Mother Board does not detect Ethernet Driver

Tags: windows-7, windows, drivers, windows-server-2008, gigabit-ethernet

I have an Intel motherboard model DH61WW and Intel i3 processor. When I tried to install Windows Server 2008 64 bit Enterprise Edition, I successfully installed it without any errors. After installing it, I tried to connect to the internet with my ethernet jack, then I realized that I didn't have an Ethernet net driver installed ... so I tried to install from [INTEL download center](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/confirm.aspx?httpDown=http://downloadmirror.intel.com/18720/eng/PROWinx64.exe&lang=eng&Dwnldid=18720&DownloadType=Drivers&OSFullname=Windows%20%20Server%202008%20*), but the driver says that "R" family ethernet is not available where I installed this driver in Windows 7.

I'm stuck ... does anyone have any ideas?

In Windows Server 2008
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/78820127/Windows%20SErver%202008.png

Comment: It might be that Windows 2008 64 bit enterprise only supports certain types of adapter.  Can you confirm on their compatibility list that this adapter is recognised & supported?

Comment: Thanks @FreudianSlip !!! i'll checked this and put result here...

Comment: Was there a special reason why you didn't plug in the ethernet cable before installation?

Comment: @ott-- maybe the special reason That He Couldn't Browse The Internet Until He Had Installed An Operating System And He Wasn't Going To Try To Browse The Internet Before Installing An Operating System Because He Is Not Like You!!

Comment: It's called the intel download center, not what you called it.  I've edited your question to correct that.

Comment: @barlop What makes you think I'd like to browse the internet during installation? I've installed countless systems during the last 15 years, be it Windows, Unix or OSX, and each of it wanted to set up networking during installation. When the system should run as a server later, then the network part gets the most attention during installation.

Comment: Thanks @ott in my first attempt i try to install Windows Server 2008 without Ethernet Plugged-In. after wasting my time to get driver. i try again with Ethernet Plugged-In. but result will same.

Comment: In Windows 7
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/78820127/Windows%207.png
In Windows Server 2008 http://dl.dropbox.com/u/78820127/Windows%20SErver%202008.png

Comment: @JKPatel yeah so in Windows 2008, where you made that screenshot, right click that "Ethernet Controller" under "other devices".. choose "update driver software" and follow the instructions at this link http://sparebot.com/2013/01/20/how-to-manually-install-dh61ww-intel-desktop-board-lan-driver-for-windows-server-2008/ which I added to my answer.

Comment: when i have 15 reputation i'll give +1..
again thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this

on the intel site for your motherboard.

<s>[for your motherboard](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&ProductFamily=Desktop%20Boards&ProductLine=Intel%C2%AE%206%20Series%20Chipset%20Boards&ProductProduct=Intel%C2%AE%20Desktop%20Board%20DH61WW)

[the lan driver  PROWin8_64_18.0.exe](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=22491&lang=eng&OSVersion=Windows%208,%2064-bit*&DownloadType=Drivers)</s>

**Added**
It is a question people have on some forums. How to get drivers for Windows 2008 for that motherboard. Looks like, indeed,  Windows 2008 is not listed on the intel site for your Motherboard. But, there's hope.

This link has sreenshots specifically for dealing with the Ethernet driver. It looks from this webpage(on sparebot.com) like the driver is already there in windows server 2008, and it's just a matter of pointing Windows 2008 server to it- Intel 82579LM Gigabit Network adapter.  device manager..right click the ethernet adapter -under "other devices", then..update driver software..pick.. then choose browse rather than search. and network adapters and point to that.

http://sparebot.com/2013/01/20/how-to-manually-install-dh61ww-intel-desktop-board-lan-driver-for-windows-server-2008/

Comment: Thanks barlop...let me try to install Windows 8 supported Driver in Windows Server 2008!!!

Comment: @JKPatel thanks for the correction. I've added a link, that looks worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Use a new  adapter( ie. D-Link DFE-520TX PCI fast ethernet adapter), connect it via the PCI slot. The system will automatically detect it.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser, how will adding a new adapter resolve the problem with the existing hardware.